# bxslider : how to make pause in `onSlideBefore` ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, bxslider

is there any option in `bxslider` to make **pause** transition in `onSlideBefore` ?

something like this

```
$('#bxslider').bxSlider({
  onSlideBefore: function(){
    pause: 100
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://bxslider.com/options), you can do something like (untested) :

```
$('#bxslider').bxSlider({
  onSlideBefore: function(){
    $('#bxslider').stopAuto();
    var ctx = setTimeout(function() {
       $('#bxslider').goToNextSlide().startAuto();
       clearTimeout(ctx);
    }, 100); // delay
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply using 2 options that Bxslider has, "auto" and "pause".

***"auto"*** like the name suggests makes the slider automated without the end user having to click any buttons to scroll through and ***"pause"*** determines the *delay* between the slides. The default delay is *4000ms* if you do not specify but you can enter your own value.

So you can simply do this to have an automatted slider with a delay of 1 sec between images.

```
$('#bxslider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    pause: 1000       
});
```

Here is a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/3w35U/3/) to demonstrate this effect. Tools like jQuery, jQuery UI, BxSlider are meant to simplify things for us. So lets keep things simple.